# Find an upper bound for the minimum natural number $m$ such that $m\bmod n_1≠d_1,\dots, m\bmod n_k≠d_k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $k$ distinct natural numbers $n_1,\dots,n_k$ and $k$ natural numbers $d_1<n_1,\dots,d_k<n_k,$
find an upper bound for the minimum natural number $m$ such that $m\bmod n_1≠d_1,\dots, m\bmod n_k≠d_k,$ where $a\bmod b$ denotes the remainder of the division of $a$ by $b.$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and next time [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Question posed (in Russian, and deleted from) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452751/i-want-to-know-if-such-a-problem-is-known. Did you not like the answer I put in the comments there, Kinunen?

Answer (score 1):

If zero counts as a natural number, then there may be no $m$ satisfying all the inequalities. E.g., take the $n_i$ to be $2,3,4,6,12$, and the $d_i$ to be $0,0,1,1,11$. Then every $m$ satisfies at least one of the congruences $m\mod{n_i}=d_i$.

If zero doesn't count as a natural number, I think it is going to be hard to beat this construction: let $n_i=2^i$, $i=1,2,\dotsc,k$, and let $d_i=2^{i-1}$, $i=1,2,\dotsc,k$; then $m=2^k$.

Comment: Во-первых, 0 не является натуральным числом по определению натурального числа. Во-вторых, мне нужна математическая формула оценки в общем виде. Похоже, задача эта непростая и ещё никем не решалась.

Comment: Google translates this as, "First, 0 is not a natural number by the definition of a natural number. Secondly, I need a general mathematical formula for the assessment. It seems that this is not an easy task and no one has yet solved it." There is no such thing as *the* definition of a natural number. Some mathematicians start the naturals at $0$, some start the naturals at $1$. Let's call the answer, $f(n_1,\dotsc,n_k,d_1,\dotsc,d_k)$. The question asks for an upper bound. An upper bound in terms of what? Just in terms of $k$? Have you any results for small $k$?

Comment: Нет, результатов у меня нет: я недавно столкнулся с этой задачей. Предварительно хочу узнать, что о ней известно вообще.

Comment: Google translates this as, "No, I don't have any results: I recently ran into this problem. First I want to know what is known about it in general."

Comment: This task also arose for me for the first time, I wanted to know the answer.